# Netbeans 6.7.1: problem with macros

Tags: netbeans, macros, settings, netbeans6.7

I find the macros feature, accessed via the red circle and the grey square in the toolbar of the source editing window, in Netbeans to be a rather nifty way of getting things done quick.

However, I find it annoying how they cannot be toggled on/off. I can be typing some code, and if it contains just the first (not all) the keystrokes in one of my macros, it will skip 2 keystrokes worth of typing.

The only way I have managed to disable this is by deleting the macro entirely:
`Tools > Options > Editor > Macros`

Is there an easier way to toggle them on / off?

---

EDIT: Any biters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for abbreviated input like `in` instead of `interface`, you probably want to take a look at code templates rather than macros. Have a look at **Tools > Options > Editor > Code Templates**. These expand when you press Tab (or Space, your choice on a per-template basis). Templates can also provide indications as to where the cursor should be placed after the expansion.

Comment: @Devon, nah, the problem I am having isn't with code completion (for e.g. typing `sout+TAB` gives you `System.out.println("");`. It was about the macros where you press the record button in the toolbar within the code editing window. Thanks for your answer anyway.